# finding all candidate keys of relation

Tags: database, database-normalization, functional-dependencies

I am following the algorithm in [this](http://csc.lsu.edu/~jianhua/fd_slide2_09.pdf) PDF in order to find all candidate keys for my relation from the given functional dependencies.

I have found that all my attributes are middle ground attributes and therefore have no neccesary attributes. Step 4 of the algorithm (page 6) says: `Let L be the list of all non-empty subsets of M (the middle-ground attributes)`. However I have 7 middle ground attributes so that would mean I need 127 elements in L. Am I doing something wrong?

Please could someone explain how I should be finding candidate keys given a set of functional dependencies?

Comment: is there a specific language that you are using? If there is, we can re-tag the question for you so you can get more help. Welcome to the site ;)

Comment: Hi, there is no specific language that I am aware of. I am just trying to learn database design and constraints, not sure how to compute candidate keys. Can't think of any other tag other than database.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

The paper you cite indeed suggests that you need to start with L having 127 elements. Do not forget that the size of L can be rapidly reduced once a set of middle-ground attributes is found that can complement the set of necessary attributes to a candidate key.

Answer (score 0):

The step 4:in the pdf computes all the superkey not the candidate key..You wont get 127 candidate keys..

Here is the difference between Candidate and Super key:

**Super Keys**: Super key stands for superset of a key.
A Super Key is a set of one or more attributes that are taken collectively and can identify all other attributes uniquely.

**Candidate Keys**:
Candidate Keys are super keys for which no proper subset is a super key. In other words candidate keys are minimal super keys.

And let us consider an example:
    The relation be **R(A,B,C,D,E)**

The *functional dependencies* are:

> A→BCDE This means the attribute 'A' uniquely determines the other attributes B,C,D,E.
>   BC→ADE This means the attributes 'BC' jointly determines all the other attributes A,D,E in the relation.

Primary Key :A

Candidate Keys :A, BC

Super Keys : A,BC,ABC,AD

ABC,AD are not Candidate Keys since both are not minimal super keys.

Hope this helps